# Scrollview visible but not scrollable on a Page

Tags: wpf, scrollview

After searching for posts regarding ScrollView not showing I couldn't find one example that is similar with mine.

Refer to the code below, my ScrollView is visible but it is not scrollable. I wonder which part I need to change to make it work?

```
  <Page x:Class="Apps"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"  

  Title="Apps"      
  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto" Height="auto">

<ScrollViewer>   
    <StackPanel>

    <Label  Content="All applications stored on desktop computer" Height="28" Name="Label2" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />


            <Grid Margin ="10"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="gridApps" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="auto">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>     


   </StackPanel>
   </ScrollViewer>
   </Page>
```

Comment: Where is the content inside of your Grid? What happens if you put a fixed Height on your RowDefintion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like setting Height=" a value here" at ScrollViewer works

```
  <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="auto"    verticalScrollBarVisibility="auto" Width="auto" Height="600">

    <StackPanel  x:Name="stackStores" Orientation="Vertical"  >
```

Answer (score 3):

Your scrollbars will be scrollable when width or height of ScrollViewer's content will be greater then its own width or height. Try this and you'll see it:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer" Margin="10" Width="100" Height="224" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
   <StackPanel Name="stackPanel" Width="200" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Yes I tried putting height at StackPanel and it is showing. However I'm populating my grid dynamically thus I want my Height at StackPanel to be auto based on my grid.. any idea how to set it to auto and at same time allow ScrollViewer to work?

Comment: hmmm... something strange... I've 'put' a label into your grid:
`<Label Name="l1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,500,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>` and this line in code-behind: `l1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;` and... vertical srollbar was enabled

Comment: try to do the same...) I think there is can be problem with populating of your grid)

Comment: Anthony, I've tried and it does not work. My grid is working fine as items can be populated and there is no error

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you didn't tried this (although, I'm not sure this solves your problem):

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```

or

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
```

(second option will be a little faster).